# I click upvote, the score becomes negative one (from zero)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I was trying to upvote an answer, but the score became negative rather than positive.

[image: Video showing issue]

Comment: You already upvoted, and by clicking upvote again you undid your upvote, substracting one vote.

Comment: Please look into screen capture software (that produces GIFs, specifically). Infinitely easier than pointing a camera at a screen, both for the maker and for the viewers.

Answer (score 12):

It was 0 with your upvote (the up button was orange). You clicked the up arrow again which **removes** your upvote. So, without your upvote, it isn't 0 anymore, now it is -1.

Comment: I think what might be quite confusing here is that when I saw the question, it was definitely on score 0. Then I suspect someone else might have decreased one; does it update asynchronously when other people make changes?

Comment: @malthe It appears you have upvoted an answer that two other people have downvoted in a short span of time. Are you sure what you are doing is correct?

Comment: @JohnDvorak actually my upvote was a mistake, but then I was like what is going on here, the arrows work in a crazy way. But I get the issue now. There's perhaps a slight usability issue in that it's hard to realize what's going on when there's asynchronous changes and the issue hasn't "settled" yet.

Comment: @malthe understood, thanks. I don't consider it a usability issue, though I do see how it might confuse people. Normally the score updates even if you don't click the arrow, but that update can break temporarily on a flaky connection, so perhaps that's what happened to you?

Comment: @malthe I think that I already saw somewhere here on MSE someone complaining that clicking the upvote button to remove an upvote is not very intuitive and makes sense only when you are already used to it, so it is really some kind of usability issue. However, I don't have a link for that right now.

Comment: Seems perfectly intuitive to me, you are clicking on the same button, to reverse the vote.  Only possible obviously after an edit to a contribution happens.